# Choose colormap for a "flat" function with steep gradient regions (Euler Gamma function)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to produce some decent plots and as an example I would like to plot the Euler Gamma function in the complex plane, like done on [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html), see first plot on the left, second row, somewhere mid-page.
The function diverges on the real axis and "squashes" the colorscale, I tried to eliminate values above a threshold masking the numpy array, but it looks awful.

My best attempt so far uses transparency as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from scipy.special import gamma
x = np.linspace(-5,5,250)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,250)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.real(gamma(xx + 1j*yy))
# Alpha channel based on Z values
# Null transparency to values whose absolute value is > .0001 
alphas = Normalize(0, .3, clip=True)(np.abs(Z))
alphas = np.clip(alphas, .3, 1)  # alpha value clipped at the bottom at .3

# Figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(Z, alpha=alphas, cmap = "hsv")

# Some contours for the show
ax.contour(Z[::-1], levels=[-.1, .1], colors='k', linestyles='-')
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

[image: Real part of Euler Gamma function on the complex plane]

It still is not too informative nor pretty, for example I lose all the details, say the "striations" starting from the real axis on the page I linked.
I think the colormap could be improved, or maybe there are other techniques, would be grateful for an advice thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a couple of changes.

- Use [`ax.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) that way you can set the x and y coordinates (this is mostly important if you decide to change the range of the variables). But one of the other benefits of using `pcolormesh` is that you can use the `shading="gouraud"` argument to make a smoother plot.
- Rather than dealing with all the normalization, which will alter the colors, just create a masked array to mask the regions outside of the desired range.
- Add the x and y coordinates to the contour as well (if you changed to `pcolormesh` above and don't make this change then the plots won't line up).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import gamma

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 250)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 250)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.real(gamma(xx + 1j*yy))
Z_max = 0.5
Z_min = -Z_max
Z_masked = np.ma.array(Z, mask=(Z>Z_max)|(Z<Z_min))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, Z_masked, cmap="hsv", shading="gouraud")

ax.contour(x, y, Z_masked[::-1], levels=[-.1, .1], colors='k', linestyles='-')
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks, very instructive